# How to obtain System.Web.Http.Tracing.dll?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, diagnostics

I read about Web API having its own TraceWriter implementation with 2012.2, for example [here](http://himanshudesai.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/web-api-introduction-to-systemdiagnosticstracewriter/), among other sources.

I am now using VS2013 with .NET 4.5.1 and the EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing is nowhere to be found. It's meant to be defined in the [HttpConfigurationTracingExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfigurationtracingextensions.enablesystemdiagnosticstracing(v=vs.100).aspx) class which resides in the System.Web.Http.Tracing.dll. However, this assembly is nowhere to be found - not in list of assemblies in the Add Reference dialog, not in GAC.

Where is this assembly supposed to come from? Docs say it's part of .NET Framework 4, which I have installed. Also installed the ASP.NET Web API 2 Tracing 5.0.0 NuGet package. Is there some update? Should I re-install .NET Framework?

I know it's not a big deal to implement ITraceWriter myself but it bothers me not to know what happened with the built-in implementation.

Answer (score 13):

Just install needed NuGet Package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing -Version 5.0.0
```

It's a little bit strange, but it is the right package

http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.tracing

Answer (score 6):

If you installed the Tracing 5.0.0 NuGet package, it should be correctly included in your project. The moment it is installed, I believe a separate text file should open in VS showing the code you should include in your WebApiConfig.cs file.

I haven't created a Web API 2 project from scratch (only upgraded from pre-5.0 to 5.0 projects), but this is the code that should reside in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
// To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
// For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

And that should be it, if the package is installed correctly, tracing should now be used in your project.